# Can't disable buffering on a cgi using nginx, fastcgi and bash

Tags: bash, nginx, fastcgi, server-sent-events, buffering

I want to make a CGI that launches a program and displays the output in the web-browser in real-time. Real-time here means as soon as a line of output is produced by the program it should be displayed on the browser page.

I choose to write it in bash to wrap the program execution so I can process request parameters.

```
webbrowser -> nginx+fastcgi -> bash -> program
```

I have a testing program that outputs one line every half a second, 10 times.

I thought I could declare a plain text context type in response header and then exec the program.

Unfortunately the output appears in the browser only at the end of the execution all at once. I tested it in Firefox and curl.

I have tested many options and any combination of them to workaround the issue :

- disable buffering in nginx with `fastcgi_buffering off` directive
- add `X-Accel-Buffering` header
- use `stdbuf -oL program`
- use xml http request (XHR) + server side event (SSE) instead of plain text.

Nothings works.

I guess the buffering issue is between nginx and bash but I find no way to disable it.

What can I try ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, recently I answered a question somewhat related to this one, the nginx output was received via XHR. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64680445/ajax-continous-response-of-php-script-output/64691037#64691037) answer, maybe it helps somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no way to fix buffering issue in my chain. I tried perl instead of bash with no luck.

So I choose to fill the buffers : after each line of output of the controlled program I echo a bunch of '\0'. Since this content can not be process as a plain text by the web browser, I use the server sent event approach.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

printf "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
printf "Content-type: text/event-stream\r\n"
printf "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n"
printf "X-Accel-Buffering: no\r\n"
printf "\r\n"

flush() {
    padding=4100
    dd if=/dev/zero bs=$padding count=1 2>/dev/null
}

subprogram | while read l;
do
    printf "data: ${l}\n\n"
    flush
done
```

The wrapping page looks like that :

```html
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Server-sent events demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <pre></pre>
<script>
var evtSource = new EventSource('/sse.sh?subprogram');
var pre = document.querySelector('pre');
evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
  pre.textContent += e.data + '\n';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The web browser, in that case, takes care of removing extra '\0'.

The drawback is that the cgi output is far larger than the program output.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but to resolve this issue, I implemented a custom modification in the fcgiwrap code.

The root of the problem in fcgiwrap was the absence of an explicit call to `FCGI_fflush()`, even when there was stdout pipe was flushed.

To address this, I suggest cloning my fcgiwrap repository from GitHub using this link: [fcgiwrap repository](https://github.com/fnclovers/fcgiwrap.git). This should help in resolving the issue.

Comment: thanks for considering this question. the patch look interesting. I finally manage to compile it and run it with systemd. unfortunately, it does not change the behavior compare to the upstream one, at least on my machine :(